# SSIS System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException How to debug

Tags: ssis

I am trying to access a third party web service via SSIS (Web Service Task). When running the package, I get this error:

```
The Web Service threw an error during method execution. 
    The error is: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at CC.AppCode.Vb.ExportService.ExportXML(String connection, String start_date, String end_date, String custom_param1, String custom_param2, String custom_param3)
```

How would one go about debugging this? I have access to the WSDL file. It really does not tell me much, but what variables. Is it possible to tell if a variable is required? I do not see any other documentation available for this web service.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your code, one suggestion is to write your code in a console app for debugging and then copy/paste it into SSIS package script task, way easier for debugging and updating/making changes.

Comment: I updated the error. the error states that the webservice threw an error.. The function ExportXML is not something that I developed... issue with webservice possibly?

Comment: If that is inside the service it looks like that variable is required but is not being accounted for in the code properly.  Try passing that variable to it.  Otherwise not much you can do to debug if it is not your code causing the issues.

Comment: well thats what i thought.. i tried passing variables